# Blender 2.79 interface freeze

Tags: interface, windows, error

I've experienced a pretty unusual error. An issue I cannot explain enough to find it on Google. The error goes like this. When Blender starts, everything looks fine, the console shows up for a moment, and then the main window appears. But, while normally the gray background quickly changes to normal Blender interface, in my case, it stays gray. Now, it's getting weirder. When I move the window or resize it, window updates. When I click on something inside the interface nothing happens unless I move/resize the window which triggers the update of the interface.
I have no idea what is happening.

In case if needed I attach my spec-sheet:
Dell Inspiron Inspiron 5558; Intel Core i3-5005U 2GHz; Intel HD Graphics 5500;

Comment: Clearly an issue with your GPU or graphics card driver. Intel Cards are well known for low performance and graphics glitches. Update your graphics drivers to the latest available version, if that doesn't help I'm afraid youl have to purchase a better one.

Comment: Well, that's weird, because it was working fine for over a year, and now suddenly decided not to cooperate with me. Is it possible to maybe downgrade graphics drivers?

Comment: Depends, it generally is. Just download the desired version and install over the current. Have you recently made any hardware changes to the computer, or updated or upgraded your operating system? It may also be a symptom of poor health or dying hardware.

Comment: No, I haven't done anything to my laptop. It's less than 2 years! How can it be dying so fast! Fortunately, I'll get an Eve V eventually in like January/February, so hopefully, my Dell will last until that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've worked out a solution by accident. It is a pretty unusual situation because actually, I have no idea why that solution was valid.

**Solution: Switch from high contrast theme to a normal one in Windows.**

For some reason, the Blender interface was unresponsive while Windows is in high contrast mode. When changed to a normal theme, everything is working just fine.

Comment: Hidden feature of the Windows

Comment: Please write a detailed bug report about this at https://developer.blender.org